# How to clear all the entries in the Find listbox?

Tags: notepad++

I want to clear all the search strings I entered in the Find dialog. How to achieve that?

Comment: If you want Notepad++'s search (and replace) history of recent entries to be cleared (or at least trimmed) whenever you exit the program, this can be easily done in its configuration files: Open `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\config.xml` with `notepad.exe` (!). In that file, find the opening `FindHistory` tag. Among that tag's attributes, change `nbMaxFindHistoryPath` and `nbMaxFindHistoryFilter` from `10` to `1`, and `nbMaxFindHistoryFind` and `nbMaxFindHistoryReplace` from `10` to `0`. (https://github.com/delight-im/Knowledge/blob/master/Windows.md)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[ajibanda++ has the answer](http://www.ajibanda.com/2011/07/clear-search-history-on-notepad.html):

> 1. First, locate the application data folder of notepad++. This should be
>      located at:
>
>    - for XP `C:\Documents and Settings\[REPLACE_WITH_USER]\Application Data\Notepad++`
>    - For Vista or Win7 it should be somewhere on: 
>        `C:\Users\[REPLACE_WITH_USER]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++`
>
>    NOTE: This is a hidden folder so it is advisable to make the hidden folders viewable.
> 2. Locate and open config.xml to notepad for editing. **Take note use
>      notepad not notepad++**, for some reason, editing it on notepad++
>      doesn't save the updates you'll be doing.
> 3. Delete the lines with tags:
>
>    - to remove, "search" history: `<Find name="[REPLACE_WORD]".../>`
>    - to remove "replace" history : `<Replace name="[REPLACE_WORD]" ..../>`
> 4. Save config.xml. If Notepad++ is open, close and then re-open it
>      again.

Comment: For Windows XP/Vista/7/8 you can just use %APPDATA%\Notepad++ to go directly there from Run.

Comment: Notepad++ stores the Find History in memory when you open it, which is why modifying config.xml _in Notepad++_ does not clear history.

Comment: Thanks, useful to clear when used find/replace with some secrets :-/

Comment: An important thing to note: Notepad++ MUST be closed when this is being changed in notepad.exe else the changes will not be reflected (that's also why you can't use Notepad++ to make these changes)

Answer (score 5):

**The easy way**: Fill the search history with 10 new entries (e.g. `1`, `2`, `3`, ..., `9`, `0`), then restart Notepad++ and the older entries are gone.

This is also very quick, because you just need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each digit to execute these 10 searches.

Comment: Honestly if I only want to spend 10 seconds to do something the developer has been neglecting to implement for all time, this is _the_ right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this feature wasn't available in previous versions. However, with version 8.6, in the Find window, a history item can be cleared by pressing the delete key while hovering it.

Comment: very nice, you are a very good explorer to find such a functionality hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

I guess things have moved on; v 8.2.1, simply right-click on the results window at the left-hand-side, and one of the options is "clear search"

Comment: This is clearing the search **result**, not the history.

Comment: Yes, true. I wasn't paying enough attention.